# run RTK dispatch on gesture start with React Native

Tags: react-native, redux-toolkit, gesture

this is my code:

```
import {
  Button,
  FlatList,
  NativeSyntheticEvent,
  Text,
  TextInput,
  TextInputFocusEventData,
  View,
} from "react-native";
import { MissionStoreType } from "../../types/Missions.types";
import { globalStyles } from "../../styles/globals.styles";
import { useAppDispatch, useAppSelector } from "../../redux/app/hooks";
import {
  MissionSelector,
  addMission,
  convertToChild,
  editMissionTitle,
  focusedMissionSelector,
  openMissionChildren,
  removeMission,
  setFocusedMission,
} from "../../redux/features/MissionsSlice";
import {
  Directions,
  Gesture,
  GestureDetector,
} from "react-native-gesture-handler";

interface MissionProps {
  id: string;
  index: number;
  nestLevel: number;
}

const Mission: React.FC<MissionProps> = ({
  id,
  nestLevel,
  index,
}: MissionProps) => {
  const dispatch = useAppDispatch();
  const mission: MissionStoreType = useAppSelector(MissionSelector(id));
  const focusedMission = useAppSelector(focusedMissionSelector);

  const rightFling = Gesture.Fling()
    .enabled(index > 0)
    .direction(Directions.RIGHT)
    .onStart(() => {
      dispatch(convertToChild({ id, index })); // convertToChild is empty action! (didnt do anything...)
    });

  const leftFling = Gesture.Fling()
    .enabled(nestLevel > 0)
    .direction(Directions.LEFT)
    .onStart(() => console.log("fling left"));

  const gestures = Gesture.Simultaneous(rightFling, leftFling);

  const handleTextInputBlur = () => {
    dispatch(setFocusedMission(null));
    if (mission.text === "") dispatch(removeMission({ id, index }));
  };

  return (
    <GestureDetector gesture={gestures}>
      <View>
        <View style={globalStyles.rowContainer}>
          <View style={{ width: nestLevel * 20 }} />
          <Button
            title="del"
            onPress={() => dispatch(removeMission({ id, index }))}
          />
          <TextInput
            onFocus={() => dispatch(setFocusedMission(id))}
            onBlur={handleTextInputBlur}
            style={globalStyles.flex1}
            value={mission.text}
            onChangeText={(text) => dispatch(editMissionTitle({ id, text }))}
            onSubmitEditing={() => dispatch(addMission({ id, index }))}
            autoFocus={focusedMission === id}
          />
          {mission.children.length > 0 && (
            <Button
              title="open"
              onPress={() => dispatch(openMissionChildren(id))}
            />
          )}
        </View>
        {mission.open && mission.children.length > 0 && (
          <FlatList
            data={mission.children}
            keyExtractor={(item) => item}
            renderItem={({ item, index: childrenIndex }) => (
              <Mission
                id={item}
                nestLevel={nestLevel + 1}
                index={childrenIndex}
              />
            )}
          />
        )}
      </View>
    </GestureDetector>
  );
};

export default Mission;
```

i use Expo to run my app.
i try to do some store changes when i swipe to the right on a mission, but, my app totally crush..
what it can be?
thanks!

i try to use runOnJS and runOnUI functions from react native reanimated.
at first i has some state changing but i remove all of them to see if there is the problem.

Comment: I don't see any overt issue in the code you shared. Can you [edit] to clarify what "my app totally crush" means exactly? Are there any errors in the terminal or console that may provide any insight what any issue or problem might be? Think you could create an [Expo Snack](https://snack.expo.dev/) demo that reproduces the issue we could inspect live?